# Spring annotation MVC return 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, model-view-controller

I have built a Spring MVC skeleton Helloworld app that returns 404.  here is the code:

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloWorldController {
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/helloworld**"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("helloworld");
    return model;
  }
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[]{ServletConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() { return new String[]{"/"}; }
}

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages =  "com.tmlink.springmvc.controller.*")
public class RootConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
            = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
  }
}

@Configuration
public class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {}
```

There is no XML config and helloworld.jsp is in WEB-INF/views/helloworld.jsp

When requesting http://localhost:8080/helloworld.jsp I get a 404.

The log from Tomcat at startup:

```
Jun 02, 2015 1:03:56 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jun 02, 2015 1:03:56 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 02 13:03:56 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 02, 2015 1:03:56 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Registering annotated classes: [class com.tmlink.springmvc.springAdmin.RootConfig]
Jun 02, 2015 1:03:57 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 02 13:03:56 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 02, 2015 1:03:57 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 924 ms
Jun 02, 2015 1:04:00 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [3,122] milliseconds.
Jun 02, 2015 1:04:00 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Jun 02, 2015 1:04:00 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Jun 02 13:04:00 CEST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Jun 02, 2015 1:04:00 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Registering annotated classes: [class com.xxxxx.springmvc.springAdmin.ServletConfig]
Jun 02, 2015 1:04:00 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 49 ms

Tomcat version: 7.0.56, Java version: 1.7.0.67.
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: try removing the "/" before helloworld and your new url would be like localhost:8080/APP_NAME/helloworld there is no need to provide the extension of .jsp.

Comment: Sorry, did not work. And the HelloWorld examples I have seen uses the "/".

Comment: try changing your view resolver with UrlBasedViewResolver.

Comment: Tried that, and the 404 is gone.  But the jsp is not displayed.

Comment: Can you check you console? Any back ground error? or Anything in the logs? If no error from tomcat that means your redirection seems to be working, try debugging your code, also check your JSP. I would suggest try putting some simple <h1> remove all other code from JSP.

Comment: Did that, no error messages and nothing in the log. Tried a simple jsp page too, view source in the browser yields nothing. I will try to change the log level for the Spring classes, but it is apparently something that requires some work.

Comment: Try debug of  the source code in eclipse or other IDE .. :) :)

Comment: That is probably the way to go. Why dont you post an answer so I can give you credits for your effort?

Comment: If your issue is resolved then I can post without this I can't :) :) :)

Comment: If your problem is not resolved, please post your code on github I will review it correct it and let you know :)

Comment: @Bilbo: found the error, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Change to

> @RequestMapping("/*")

Answer (score 0):

Found the error:

@ComponentScan(basePackages =  "com.tmlink.springmvc.controller.*")

should have been:

@ComponentScan(basePackages =  "com.tmlink.springmvc.controller")

in RootConfig class.